# Installing a WordPress theme locally using WAMP?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wordpress-theming, wamp, local

Hello I am trying to upload a theme locally using WAMP the zip file is 19.4 mb if that is any useful information.

When I go to upload the theme I am getting the message:

> Are you sure you want to do this?
>
> Please try again.

Does anyone know why or have any suggestion to why this is happening ?

Comment: try adding the theme manually first, path:wordpress_folder/wp-content/themes/. Unzip theme file here. And try to activate @ChrisLad

Comment: @parthmahida that did work tho without the demo content sadly any idea's?

Comment: In your theme folder there will be a folder for demo data with .xml file . I am moving this comment to answer so you can accept as approved answer.@ChrisLad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the theme manually first, path:wordpress_folder/wp-content/themes/. Unzip theme file here. And try to activate.